# UK to Iran by car - insurance question

Tags: europe, driving, automobiles, insurance, iran

My husband and I are Australians who want to buy a car in the UK and drive it to Iran through Europe (incl. Eastern Europe), Turkey, Armenia, Azerbaijan etc. We want to leave ASAP once we have the practicalities sorted.

Our plan is to then drive back to the UK by Christmas and sell the car there (this way we don't have to pay for export etc).

It has been much more difficult than expected finding out about **insurance** for this, and I was hoping someone might be able to help us. Most importantly, we want to have third party liability insurance for the entire trip.

So, our questions are:

1. Has anyone else done this trip?
2. Did you buy international insurance? A few insurance companies (including Clements that I read about on a Horizons Unlimited thread) have said they will cover us for Europe and Turkey, but not Iran (or the 'Stans' area).
3. If you did manage to buy international insurance that covered Iran etc, who did you go through and how much did it cost (roughly)?
4. The other option we are considering is buying insurance for Europe and Turkey, then buying insurance at the border for these other countries (eg Iran). Does anyone know if this is possible, or have you done it? Is it easy enough to do?
5. Any other tips on sorting out the practicalities for such a trip, especially around insurance, would be very much appreciated.

P.S. We are buying the car in the UK instead of continental Europe because as Australians on a tourist visa we can't buy a car in Europe without residency. We know that they drive on the other side in the UK, so are looking for a left-hand vehicle there (and if that's not possible, we'll just have to cope!)

Comment: do you think it's a good idea do buy a car in the UK (right hand drive) and drive it across many countries with left hand drive?

Comment: @AakashM Quick google search reveals that HU is in fact Horizons Unlimited. Here is the OP's [cross post](http://www.horizonsunlimited.com/hubb/middle-east/uk-iran-back-insurance-question-77408).

Comment: Thanks Aakashm that's fine and I have revised the original post to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: Make sure to check your country's and insurance company's country's policies on Iran, many have sanctions that forbid people to send/use money there, much like Americans in Cuba

Comment: 5 questions in one??

Comment: As a single-topic question about how to be insured for third party liability across this range of countries is a good one. I would not imagine it to be easy at all yet I've seen documentaries and travelogues where people have done similar adventures and assume some of them must have had some insurance...

Comment: All the specific questions are related to the insurance issue, the UK/Europe thing should have been clear even before the edit, I think the question is great, +1 from me.

Comment: I'd be more worried about visa for all those countries, and repairs/servicing the car than about insurance. Can get the latter no doubt if you throw enough money at it, the rest?

Comment: @hippietrail if you're a film/TV crew or a have a charity backing you, often a lot of avenues suddenly open that are otherwise closed. Sponsorships are good and usually cheap PR after all :)

Comment: @jwenting: Possibly, but they might also have proffessional or dedicated fixers who spend a lot of time making lots of phonecalls figuring it all out too.

Comment: @hippietrail probably both, yes. Met a Kazakh crew once who were driving Landcruisers around the world. They were spending almost as much time waiting at embassies and consulates for visas as they were driving.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I think you may struggle to find a left hand drive car for sale in the UK. Not saying it is impossible, but it will be difficult.

Comment: @AnneyBelle: Is this for an adventure/challenge? Or is it because you imagined it might be an easy/cheap/practical way to do a trip?

Comment: it's trivial to buy a normal left hand drive car in the UK.  there is a huge market for it.  you can instantly google any of the huge companies which do this, example http://www.lhd-car.com

Answer (score 8):

I haven't done the trip but I know some who did it as part of the [Mongol Rally](http://www.theadventurists.com/mongol-rally/).  I checked with them - being Australians, they bought their insurance through [1Cover](http://www.1cover.com.au/) so they definitely covered the whole trip including driving from Europe (London) through to Iran and beyond.  [The Rally](http://www.theadventurists.com/mongol-rally-paperwork/) itself suggests [Campbell Irvine](http://www.campbellirvine.com/), which suggests they will also cover that scenario.

The participants also suggest that, based off their research, if you're not in the rally any insurance company should be fine as long as you have the right licenses and drive appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long to post in a comment, not the answer to your question, but needed to know for Azerbaijan and Armenia. There are no diplomatic relations between Armenia and Azerbaijan, largely due to the ongoing Nagorno-Karabakh conflict.

From [U.S Department of State](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/Azerbaijan.html) Entry, Exit and Visa Requirements section.

> - Law enforcement officials have at times detained individuals from Armenia or with Armenian surnames for questioning or denied them entry
>     into the country.
> - Please be aware that traveling to the region of Nagorno-Karabakh and the surrounding territories via Armenia could make you ineligible
>     to travel to Azerbaijan in the future.

from [Wikitravel](https://wikitravel.org/en/Azerbaijan) Get in section.

> - Entry will be refused to citizens of Armenia, citizens of Armenian    ancestry, and anyone carrying products made in Armenia or with
>     Armenian labelling. You may also be refused entry depending on how
>     many trips you have made to Armenia in the past so do stay alert.
> - Anybody showing proof of entry to Nagorno-Karabakh without prior    consent from the Azerbaijani government will either be deported or
>     arrested by the immigration authorities and will then be permanently
>     banned from entering the country. Should anybody enter the separatist 
>     territory by accident, it is strongly recommended that they clear the 
>     situation with their local Azerbaijani consultate since the local
>     justice system will do absolutely nothing to support your case.
> - Any foreign national having a visa to visit Armenia may expect to be    hassled/harassed by border patrol.

Comment: This is an interesting answer regarding Azerbaijan/Armenia travel, but do you have a source for this information?

Comment: @MikeHarris updated answer